# Ionic Android - how do you rename the built output file?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, gradle

In Ionic 5, doing an Android build with `ionic cordova build android` produces an output file called `app-debug.apk`, or `app-release.apk`. How can I rename that file?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a file `build-extras.gradle` somewhere in your Ionic project.
2. In `build-extras.gradle`, add the following to set the name of the output file to a property `myOutputName`:

```
android  {
    setProperty("archivesBaseName", myOutputName)
}
```

3. In `config.xml`, add the following within `<platform name="android">`, to make the build use your `build-extras.gradle` file:

```
<resource-file src="path/to/build-extras.gradle" target="build-extras.gradle" />
```

4. Build the app with command:

```
ionic cordova build android -- -- --gradleArg=-PmyOutputName=NewFileName
```

This will produce a file called `NewFileName.apk`.